# A nice way of saying 'decline' in a job rejection letter

Tags: meaning

> Dear Mr.Nameless,
>
> Thank you for considering me for the position of [position] at [company]. I appreciate the time spent for me.
>
> Your organization’s vision and mission resonates with my values, and I am glad for the challenging opportunity you are offering me. [?However] I would like to say that I have accepted another opportunity last week Friday with a Robotics Firm that closely aligns with my skills and career goals. After much thought, I regret to **decline** your offer.
>
> Thank you for your time and understanding.
>
> Sincerely,

I am not really happy about using 'decline'. I've tried to substitute it with

- downturn
- turn down

Still feel as if something is missing. I want to be a bit more positive with the wording. I can't find it. For example, instead of saying 'I am not hungry' using the word 'not' making it sound negative 'I am full' or 'I have just eaten' is relatively more positive. I would like to use a more positive word rather 'decline' if that's possible? I've looked at synonyms but couldn't find the right one, perhaps there is a different way of structuring the sentence?

**Q:** Is there a more pleasant/positive way of 'decline' in the aforementioned context?

Comment: Generally, *decline/ reject* are avoided; *unable to accept* is the prefered alternative.

Comment: I don't think you need the last sentence. After saying you have accepted the other position, you are  implicitly  declining their offer. Just say that you thank  them for the opportunity they have offered  you!!

Comment: Use the word withdraw: "I'd like to withdraw my name from the available candidates"

Comment: @Othya That wouldn’t work if (s)he’s actually already been offered the position.

Comment: Get to the point a little quicker.

Comment: @Othya How about "After much thought, I would like to regretfully withdraw my application. "?

Comment: @HotLicks, would you recommend I remove some things?

Comment: "While I found your offer attractive, I have decided to accept a position with Smith & Co."  Something along those lines.  Have pity on the guy who has to read a dozen of these letters every day.

Comment: Definitely avoid regret unless you wanted to accept but can't for reasons out of your control.

Comment: @IanMacDonald How about "After much thought, I would like to regretfully withdraw my application." as opposed to just "regret"?

Comment: @3kstc: no, avoid regret (and any derivation thereof). Why not just "After much thought, I would like to withdraw my application."? Why does there have to be an emotion attached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing about *decline* that you should be worried about in my opinion.  It isn't a harsh word for the situation.  However, if you want to avoid sounding negative, then **state the positive instead**:

> After much thought, I have chosen to accept the offer at Robotics Firm instead.

Of course, this is redundant as you've already stated that earlier in your letter.  If you want to avoid using the word *decline*, just omit the sentence containing this word.  Everything you need to say is already stated elsewhere.

Comment: Would the 'firm' be with a capital F? or would robotics and firm be both in lower case?

Comment: @3kstc I was assuming that you were using a placeholder for the actual name of the organization.  If you are referring anonymously to the firm by indicating what they do rather than who they are, you should not capitalize at all, since you are not using a proper name.  You should also include the indefinite article, i.e.: **a robotics firm** not **Robotics Firm**.

Comment: I wasn't place holding, I do not want to disclose the name of the company I work for to Mr.Nameless. So to reconfirm the sentence would be "... last week Friday with a robotics firm that closely..." ?

Comment: @3kstc - That is correct.

Comment: What would be an appropriate email subject, in your opinion?

Comment: @3kstc - Depending on how many jobs you think may be posted, you might want to go with "Response to offer of employment" or be more specific "Response to offer of job {position name/job posting ID etc.}" where you provide the actual job in question.

Answer (score 4):

Why not drop "***decline***" altogether.

> However, after a lot of contemplation, I have accepted another
>   opportunity with a robotics firm that closely aligns with my skills
>   and career goals.

Comment: The original "after much thought" sounds better.  ( *"a lot of"* is not very formal, whereas *"contemplation"* is a very formal expression. It's not a good idea to mix different registers).

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with

> I'm afraid that I'll have to pass on the offer.

It sounds positive because *pass on* implies someone else will take the job.

Comment: "Pass" is rather informal.  Generally a higher degree of formality should be maintained.

Comment: @HotLicks I was thinking "pass" in this context would be informal, however I am not too sure about "pass on" perhaps it would be acceptable?

Comment: "Pass on" is as informal as "pass".

Comment: I don't think 'pass on' is as informal as 'pass'. Additionally, companies aren't as squeamish about informal language as they used to be. Additionally, since I'm not going to work for them, I don't have to worry about them judging me if I can achieve my goal of positive tone using a slightly informal phrase.